# Has the retina screen effectively made dead pixels moot?

Tags: ipad, iphone, display

Now the new iPad has a retina screen, does that mean we can't see dead pixels anymore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will still be able to see the defect.

What retina means is that once two items with similar contrast get close enough together, you can't tell them apart - it appears to be one item.

Along a line, for instance, you can't tell where each pixel that makes the line is, but you can clearly see the edge created by the line on the contrasting background.

A dead pixel creates a contrast you'll be able to see.  If you have two dead pixels next to each other, you might think you only have one.  But you will be able to see them if the pixels surrounding them contrast.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can still see dead pixels perfectly well - if you go close enough.

Actually, I received two new iPads - both with a few dead pixels (always black).

It was in both cases a patch of dead pixels, for one device I estimate around 4-6 and for the other 2-3; the patches were in different locations.

As the pixels are now so small, dead pixels are far less disturbing - nevertheless, I sent back both iPads because of that.

Comment: Did you simply return the iPads or did you get them replaced with non-dead-pixel models?

Comment: The second was the replacement for the first one, and when I found dead pixels again I returned it for a refund...

Comment: Wow, bad luck with two defective iPads.

Answer (score 1):

You can still see dead pixels on the new iPad screen, but they are less obvious than on previous models.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please consider providing more detail in your answer to make it higher quality. See here for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer